# Prove that sequence $(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n}$ does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Struggling to do this as subsequences won't work. Haven't learnt cauchy sequences so trying straight from the definition.

Assume for sake of contradiction $(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n}$ converges. So for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$, such that for all $n>N$, we have $|a_n-l| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Let $\epsilon = \frac{|\sqrt{n}-l|}{2}$ be given. Then for all $n>N$, we have $|(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n}-l| \leq {|\sqrt{n} -l|}<\frac{|\sqrt{n}-l|}{2}$, so $1<\frac{1}{2}$, which is a contradiction. Hence, sequence doesn't converge to a finite limit.

$\square$

Comment: $\epsilon$ is not allowed to depend on $n.$ And generally, $|(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n}-l| \ne {|\sqrt{n} -l|}.$

Comment: Perhaps the generalisation is easier: Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $(-1)^na_n$ converges. Then $a_n\to0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay understood

Comment: Have you learnt that all convergent sequences are bounded?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes I know the proof for that. So if I take the contrapositive of that statement, by showing that the sequence is unbounded, it clearly does not converge. How would I show it is unbounded ? Basically, is it enough just to say the function will oscillate between positive and negative values which will get bigger?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Also, can't I use the ***absolute value*** rule for limits. As if the absolute value of the sequence doesn't tend to a finite limit, I can prove it diverges using the definition, then the actual sequence musn't as well ?

Comment: Suppose $s$ is an upper bound.  Then take any odd natural number $n>s^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

If a sequence is convergent, then all of its subsequences converge to the same limit.  The subsequence of odd terms are all positive and all strictly increasing.  The subsequence of even terms are all negative and all strictly decreasing.  Therefore, the two subsequences can not converge to the same limit.

So, you can bypass having to consider whether the sequence or any of its subsequences are unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

The sign changes between any two elements. Show that such a sequence can only be convergent if the limit is 0.

Then show that this sequence doesn’t have the limit 0.